# How do I fix this attribute error i my calculation step?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to determine which loans in a loan portfolio exceed the FHFA County Loan Limit to project impact of upcoming law changes for a study.  I've had versions of the code work with a small (14k loans) sample set, but when importing the full portfolio (5.6m) the code does not work.  I'm definitely pretty new to Python, my experience is limited to SAS and R, and that's admittedly rusty.

As I don't have access to live data, I'm importing the data w/ chunksize of 5k which has alleviated memory issues. and I've imported the loan limit data from the FHFA website, and created a dictionary for year, state, and county code.

I also used pd.to_datetime() and a .notnull() in an attempt to remove nulls from the data and county fields.

```
def loan_calculation_new(row):
 year = row['PROCESSED_DATE'].year
 if row['PROCESSED_DATE'].month > 9:
    year += 1

 state_dict = year_dict[year]

 if row['FIPS_STATE_CODE'] not in state_dict:
    print("No State Code")
    return None

 county_dict = state_dict[row['FIPS_STATE_CODE']]
 if row['FIPS_COUNTY_CODE'] not in county_dict:
    limit = 485300

 return   
 limit = county_dict[row['FIPS_COUNTY_CODE']]
 limit > row['MTGE_LOAN_AMOUNT'].astype(int)
```

I keep getting this error when trying to run the calculation:

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'year'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I'm wondering if the issue is with my data being pipe delineated, and not being interpreted as a date.  The Sample was a .csv and seemed to work.

Comment: What is in `row`?

Comment: @ScottHunter strings, apparently :)

Comment: What are you EXPECTING to be in row?

Comment: After I did pd.to_datetime() I was expecting it to be a date-time not a string.  Which is why the error telling me it is STILL a string is confusing.  When I print a single row I'm seeing the MM/DD/YYYY format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the col `PROCESSED_DATE` is string, so you need to convert to datetime

if the row from dataframe, you can do:

```
df['PROCESSED_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PROCESSED_DATE'])
```

Comment: So, I did do that:
calc_df['PROCESSED_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(calc_df['PROCESSED_DATE'], format='%d/%m/%y')

Comment: So, after moving it around into the calculation step, it worked out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

def loan_calculation_new(row):
 year = datetime.strptime(row['PROCESSED_DATE'], "<EXPECTED FORMAT>").year
 if row['PROCESSED_DATE'].month > 9:
    year += 1
 ...
```